# How to prove a statement that contains two biconditionals: Exercise in Pinter's A Book of Abstract Algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, notation, propositional-calculus

In Pinter's A Book of Abstract Algebra, the reader is asked in Chapter 14 exercise D4 to prove the following statement:

[image: Page 143 Pinter]

I have never been asked to prove a statement that contains two **iff**s. I just wanted to confirm that the below interpretations are all correctly capturing the idea:

1. "*$H$ is normal*" is equivalent to "*$ab \in H \iff ba \in H$*"
2. $[((ab \in H \implies ba \in H) \land (ba \in H \implies ab \in H)) \implies H$ is normal] $\land \ [H$ is normal $\implies ((ab \in H \implies ba \in H) \land (ba \in H \implies ab \in H))]$

So it seems to me that I essentially need to prove 3 different "sub-statements" in order to prove the original statement. Those 3 sub-statements are:

A. $H$ is normal $\implies (ab \in H \implies ba \in H)$

B. $H$ is normal $\implies (ba \in H \implies ab \in H)$

C. $(ab \in H \iff ba \in H) \implies H$ is normal

A and B will be paired together. Is this correct?

Comment: Correct. That is how you prove the statement.

Comment: I think by symmetry A implies B.

Comment: @JustinYoung sorry, I am not familiar with "Symmetry" in this context. Why exactly does A imply B? ... Does B similarly imply A?

Comment: It is usually informal, but just imagine that the proof for A should work just as well for B by switching the letters, as there is a clear symmetry in the statements, or in other words, if $a$ and $b$ are really allowed to be any elements of the group, then the statements A and B say exactly the same thing.

Comment: ohhhhh. gotch ya. Cheers~